# Java 1.4 + extendible builder pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, generics, java1.4

I've hit a bit of a brick wall when it comes to implementing an extendible class that utilizes the [builder pattern](http://drdobbs.com/java/208403883?pgno=2) in java 1.4. The pattern itself works a treat but I've hit a bit of a brick wall when it comes to making it extendible due to the lack of generics.

At this point the best solution I've been able to come up with is to have an abstract inner `Builder` class within the parent. This then contains a protected constructor for all required params common to the child classes and some javadoc to inform the user they need to implement their own `build()` method which returns an object of the same type as the return class. This works if people RTFM, otherwise it breaks... which is bad. Any ideas appreciated.

note: I'm stuck working in 1.4 as that's the VM of the dedicated hardware this is designed to run on.

Comment: This will be tricky, as you don't even have covariant return types in Java 1.4

Comment: My advice would be to stop trying to be too fancy.  Just design the APIs to work with a constructor and/or old-fashioned setters.  It is not as pretty, but it will probably end up being easier for people to use.  (The best thing about banging your head against a brick wall is stopping.)

Comment: @stephen The only problem with using a group of constructors approach is that there are a large number of optional parameters. Things start to get quite messy when you are providing constructors for every possible combination or exposing the objects in illegal states in the case of setters, otherwise I entirely agree it would be the better solution.

Comment: the old-school solution to lots of optional parameters is to populate the non-default values with setters.  Or to use a Properties object or a custom configuration object if these are settings that are reused across multiple constructor calls.

Comment: Taken that route now. Re-factored a couple of things to reduce complexity and added setters where required along with some factory methods for object creation.

Answer (score 1):

One way to "fake" generics is to have the subclass pass a `Class` into the constructor.

```
public class MySuperClass {

    private final Class clazz;

    protected MySuperClass(Class clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void doSomethingGenericish(Object param) {
        // Pseudo generic check
        if (!param.getClass().isAssignableFrom(param)) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Could not cast " + param.getClass() + " as " + clazz);
        }
        // Some code
    }
}

public class MySubClass extends MySuperClass {

    protected MySubClass()
    {
        super(PseudoGenericsParameterClass.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, some sort of run-time check is going to be the best you can do, I suspect. Which, really, is the whole point of generics :-)

Comment: Unfortunately that won't allow you to add builder methods to the sub class and mix-and-match their calls freely with calls to the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are just a convenience that allows the compiler to enforce some stuff for you. If you just thoroughly document the types of things, and enforce those rules yourself, you would get the same result without generics. Heck, you could even write the generic type stuff in comments, and follow them yourself.

Comment: The issue with the builder pattern though is that your `build()` method must return an object of the type it's building. Although it would be possible to have the `build()` method just return Object this would rely on the user casting it correctly, which gets a bit messy.